# How to use purrr functions inside dplyr's select_if

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to find the shortest possible `dplyr-purr` combination.

Can I reduce the following statement which combines `select_if()` and `map_df()` ?

```
training.set.imputed %>% 
  select_if(~sum(is.na(.))>0) %>% map_df(~sum(is.na(.)))
```

I tried this:

```
training.set.imputed %>% 
  select_if(~sum(is.na(.))>0, .funs = ~sum(is.na(.)))
```

which throws this error:

> Error: `nm` must be `NULL` or a character vector the same length as `x`

What does this mean?
Any ideas how to form the `.funs` term?

Comment: What kind of output do you expect? Do you even need the funs term here?

Comment: Please share a sample of your data, current and expected ouptut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.funs` argument in `select_if` requires a renaming function, and not a mutating function, so you can do something like this with it, but you can't mutate the variable values:

```r
tibble(blah = 1:2, bleh = 3:4, bluh = c(NA, NA)) %>% 
    select_if(~ sum(is.na(.x)) > 0, .funs = toupper)

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 2 x 1
  BLUH 
  <lgl>
1 NA   
2 NA
```

If you insist on using a combination of purrr and dplyr, then this is probably your best bet *(Edit: I just noticed that G. Grothendieck gave this answer, but I'll include it anyway for the sake of completeness.)*:

```r
df %>% 
    map_df(~ sum(is.na(.))) %>% 
    select_if(~ . > 0)

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 1 x 2
      b     d
  <int> <int>
1     4     1
```

However, you can simplify it a little by just using dplyr's `summarize_if`:

```r
df %>% 
    summarise_if(anyNA, ~ sum(is.na(.)))

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 1 x 2
      b     d
  <int> <int>
1     4     1
```

Since you're really just after column sums, base R might offer the most concise option:

```r
colSums(is.na(df)) %>% 
    .[. > 0]

#### OUTPUT ####

b d 
4 1
```

### Data

```r
structure(list(a = c(2L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 11L, 
14L, 12L, 10L, 4L, 16L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 2L, 14L, 7L), b = c(10L, 
20L, 16L, NA, 6L, 1L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 8L, NA, NA, 8L, 11L, 
19L, 8L, 9L, NA, 19L), c = c(11L, 11L, 20L, 8L, 15L, 4L, 17L, 
4L, 4L, 11L, 20L, 11L, 6L, 12L, 17L, 7L, 14L, 18L, 15L, 19L), 
    d = c(19L, 16L, 17L, 14L, 8L, 19L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 13L, 7L, 19L, 
    11L, 17L, NA, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), e = c(12L, 17L, 14L, 
    5L, 8L, 19L, 8L, 3L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 17L, 14L, 5L, 8L, 
    2L, 8L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Great. The `summarize_if` solution was what I was looking for - simplify the two functions into one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the number of NAs in each column keeping only columns that have at least 1 NA.

**!)** This avoids the code duplication and does not give an error.  First calculate the number of NAs in each column and then pick out the columns that are greater than 0.

```
# test input - BOD comes with R
BOD[1,2] <- NA

BOD %>%
  map_df(~ sum(is.na(.))) %>%
  select_if(~ . > 0)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  demand
   <int>
1      1
```

**2)** This first selects out those columns with at least one NA and then finds the number of NAs in those columns giving the same result:

```
BOD %>%
  select_if(anyNA) %>%
  map_df(~ sum(is.na(.)))
```

Comment: Thanks, it does avoid the code duplication. But I'm looking for a way to make the .funs argument in select_if working...

Comment: The purpose of the `.funs` argument is to transform the column names.  For example, you could use `.funs = shQuote` to put quotes around the column names.  Don't really think it applies in the way you were thinking.

Comment: Ah thanks - this made it clear! I thought the .funs in select_if could contain a general function - but your answer makes sense if select_if only works on column names!